# How to print current username in Crystal-lang?

Tags: crystal-lang

I want to print **current** username using Crystal-lang, does anyone know how to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is still somewhat missing in the standard library. There's an ongoing discussion about it here: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/7829

Meanwhile we can quickly bind `getuid(2)` or `geteuid(2)` ourselves and combine it with [`System::User`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.0.0/System/User.html):

```
require "system/user"

lib LibC
  fun getuid : UidT
end

user = System::User.find_by id: LibC.getuid.to_s

pp user.username
```

https://carc.in/#/r/b63s